# Escaping x number of rows in Select query

Tags: sql, select

I want rows from the entire table but I only want to select rows 1,5,10,15,20,25

Table

```
ID   Col1 Col2……….
1  
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

I want to select in my result set

```
Id   Col1 Col2……….
1
5
10
15
20
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Suggested answer by @GordonLinoff or `select * from Table where Id in (1,5,10,15,20,25)` if you want to use an explicit list

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
where id = 1 or
      id % 5 = 0
```

The `%` is the modulo operator.  Some databases use a `mod()` function instead.

If `id` has gaps or other issues, you may want to do this with `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 or seqnm % 5 = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, perfect solution for the problem!